# How to toogle different modal with different content and change the button as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna toggle different models and calculate the results in form individually.

I try to avoid paste too many modal codes and found the sample [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content), however, it use the same ID, so I get stuck!

> If you click on
>
> Button A it shows Modal A with Calculate A.
>
> Button B it shows modal B with Calculate B.
>
> Button N it shows modal N with Calculate N.

Is there a way to change the button to another one? or any help?

Much appreciate!

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Form click on ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
 
  $("#buttonA").click(function () {
  var a = $("#amout").val();
  alert("Results: " + a);
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="button A">Run button A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="button B">Run button B</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="button N">Run button ...N</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Form 1-N</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          Num: <input id="amout" type="number">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonA">calculate</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add more details?. What is your actual requirement?.

Comment: @sarathsrajendran can't get the snippet works, just attached a image.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Additions between buttons? Like if I click on a button, chose a number and then click on calculate, should it output the result of that value + the values of the former buttons?

Comment: @tcj Yes! the sample above just only switch the text, I would like to add more contents and buttons and maybe hide until the button has press down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fastest way is set id for each button you want change and Change innerText of that in your Function.

**Html Tag**

```
<button id="AcceptBTN" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
         ^
         |
        Here
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
 // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.

$('#AcceptBTN')[0].innerText = recipient;   <-----------------Here

  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

GoodLuck

Comment: Thanks, but I want it not only just change the text, I will use them to do calculation in different form.

Comment: what calculation you want ?
Count Of Opened Them ? Or Other ?

Comment: Let me change more on the snippet.

Comment: @ HamidReza Heydari please check again.

Comment: If you want to pass some value between Modals The Best way using Variables.
initial them in top of page and use them every where in you page

Comment: As you see there are 3 buttons out there, but they can only open one modal at time. I would like make them open different ones and the buttons, too.

Comment: come to easy question:
1- when click some Run Buttons Open 3 modal? Or Just 1
2-What will happen in Click Modal Calculate Button?
any more?!

Comment: if you click on btnA it shows modalA with CalculateA. calculate button isn't that important.

Comment: then why not create 3 seperate modals and show them when the adequate button is clicked?

Comment: @tcj Because I got like hundreds of forms and try to avoid too much code in HTML.

Comment: @DAVE find the answer !?